# How to avoid query string parameters in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following route

```
routes.MapRoute("CreateBook", "{controller}/{action}/{slug}/{name}", new { controller = "CreateBook", action = "Index" , slug = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

For some reason, whenever I call RedirectToAction, the URL appears as

> return RedirectToAction("Parameters", new { slug=1234, name="helloworld" });

http://localhost/CreateBook/Parameters?slug=1234?name=helloworld

What I would like is

http://localhost/CreateBook/Parameters/1234/helloworld

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the `RedirectToAction` call is picking up the *default* route, not your specialised route.

By default, when you pass in route values, MVC will append the values as querystring parameters.

Did you put that route *before* the default route?

Comment: @Sir Psycho - hehe, thought so. If you haven't already, grab Phil Haack's "Route Debugger". Will save you LOTS of route debugging time.